# Interface extending multiple interfaces

Tags: spring, interface, spring-bean

i am using spring & have 2 interfaces,

```
interface A {
    public void a();
}

interface B {
    public void B();
}
```

and their implementations

```
class AImpl implements A {
    public void a(){ // TODO }
}
class BImpl implements B {
    public void b(){ // TODO }
}
```

Now I create an interface C

```
    interface C extends A, B {}
```

Is there any way I can get a bean of type C with method definations of AImpl & BImpl

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a CImpl that extends AImpl and BImpl as Java doesn't support multiple inheritance for classes.

But you can do something like this:

```
class CImpl implements C {
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public CImpl(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void a() {
        a.a();
    }

    public void b() {
        b.b();
    }
}
```

And create your CImpl with:

```
CImpl c = new CImpl (new AImpl(), new BImpl());
```

If you use Spring (as your tags imply) you can configure AImpl, BImpl and CImpl as Beans and use autowiring for the constructor of CImpl.

Comment: I understand that we cannot extend the implementations directly ( as there are multiple ). But since I have already provided implementations of these interfaces (A & B), is it not possible for spring to create an object of C. This is how it happens when you create custom repository in spring jpa.